# How to use magic store commands within a python function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, function, numpy

I have the following python functions:

```py
def fun1():
    df1 = pd.read_csv("test1.csv")
    df2 = pd.read_csv("test2.csv")
    return df1, df2


def fun2(df1, df2):
    df3 = df1
    return df1, df2, df3


def fun3(df1, df2, df3):
    df3.to_csv("df3.csv", index=False)
    %store df3  #here is the problem
    return df1, df2, df3
```

When I do the above, I get an error message like as shown below

> UsageError: Unknown variable 'df3'

However, I would like to store df3 using magic command, so I can use it other jupyter notebooks etc.

Can someone help me avoid this error?

Comment: Please fix the indentation.

Comment: While it's not super clear from the docs, it looks like `%store` saves global variables, not the function local ones.   In `%store df3`, `df3` is a string, not the variable you just defined.  It looks that up in base namespace, not the function's.  When it works `%store` displays info on what does, eg `Stored 'x' (dict)`